# Desktop/homepage shortcut to send pre-built email in one click

Tags: gmail, email, automation, home-screen-shortcuts

I'm trying to set up a way to send a pre-defined gmail email to a pre-defined recipient with a single tap from the home screen. Essentially, I'm going to use emails to trigger macro events on another device, and as I will be regularly sending these emails, (sometimes multiple times per day), I do not want to have to continuously recreate them manually. I want something like [Compose Email Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.austrianapps.android.compose), only I would like the recipient, subject and body to all be filled in already and for the email to be sent as soon as the shortcut is pressed. [Email Yourself](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dzogchenltd.emailyourself) is the closest thing I could find to this, but that app is rather expensive for what should be a pretty basic function, and it still requires the user to press send after the shortcut is pressed.

Any help/advice appreciated...

Comment: @beeshyams Unfortunately the device that is receiving the emails does not have a SIM card. It might work if it could be done through WhatsApp or some other internet-based messaging service.

Comment: @beeshyams To be honest, I think I'd even take a free alternative to Email Yourself if that exists. I just really don't want to spend that much money on a very basic operation (autofilling fields in an email).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros and you need only one macro for your need) 
and easy to learn.

- Give the app all permissions it asks for and from Settings →Email settings, enter your Gmail account details.
- Create a macro as shown below (use **+** to add triggers /actions). In the send mail action fill in details of recipient and the text of mail. In pop up action enter text that you want to be displayed when you create a widget (explained in next step). Save the macro with any name.

[image]

(click to enlarge)

- From the widgets drawer of your launcher drag and drop *MacroDroid Shortcut* widget on top your screen. On the menu that opens up, assign it to the macro you saved.

Tap the shortcut to send the mail. I've tested and it works fine.

[image]

(click to enlarge)

You may edit the icon of widget to a custom one and add more bells and whistles by way of adding a sound action, scheduling to send mail at fixed times /days, or whatever you want ( endless possibilities) 
later